# SQL Server Query - Joining individual values with a full list of possible values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I couldnt think of a very good title so let me explain.

I have a list of days that students were absent (dbo.Attendance).

### [image: absent]

I also have a list of days that school was open (dbo.DateCollection).

### [image: school days]

My question is..
Is there some why for me to join/combined the two table into a list that shows each day for each student with their attendance? something like this..

Any help or direction would be well appreciated!!

[image]

Comment: Are you querying for only one calendarId at a time?

Comment: no, there are multiple calendars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  You can do this by joining the tables.  In this case, it is a bit tricky, because you have to start with a row for all students on all days, and then see if the student was present.  Let me assume that you have a `Students` table:

```
select s.personid, c.calendarid, c.date, coalesce(a.absentMinutes, 0) as absentMinutes
from Calendar c cross join
     Students s left outer join
     Attendance a
     on a.dateOccurred = c.date and
        a.personid = s.personid;
```

If you don't have students table, then you have a problem.  You can only report on students that are in the `Attendance` table.  You could do this as:

```
select s.personid, c.calendarid, c.date, coalesce(a.absentMinutes, 0) as absentMinutes
from Calendar c cross join
     (select distinct personid from Attendance) s left outer join
     Attendance a
     on a.dateOccurred = c.date and
        a.personid = s.personid;
```

Comment: As Tripp mentioned above.. I probably should have included that there are multiple calendarid's. The first query seems to work but also matched for other calendarid's that the student does not belong to.

Comment: @JonDog . . . I fixed the queries.  When I saw `calendarId`, I interpreted it as a unique id on the calendar table, which it doesn't seem to be.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the input.

I ended up using a bridge table for students as well..
This is what I have got working for me.

```
SELECT s.personid,
        dc.calendarid, 
        dc.[date], 
        coalesce(absentMinutes,0) AS absentMinutes
  FROM [dbo].[StudentCalendar] s INNER JOIN 
        [dbo].[DateCollection] dc ON s.calendarId=dc.calendarId LEFT JOIN
        [dbo].[Attendance] a ON a.dateOccurred=dc.[date] AND a.personId=s.personId
```